# ruby markdown parser with WikiWord support?

Tags: ruby, git, wiki, markdown

I am using [git-wiki](https://github.com/sr/git-wiki) for my personal note storage. It works very well, except that WikiWords are converted to links before the markdown parsing stage, using a regular expression. This messes up scores of things, for instance links that point to outside wiki pages, or block quotes (if I am quoting something, I do not want a WikiWord to be changed into a link).

Are there ruby-based Markdown parsers that understand WikiLinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best parser around is the C-based one ([upskirt](https://github.com/chobie/upskirt)/[sundown](https://github.com/tanoku/sundown)), whose ruby iteration is red carpet:

https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet

It is better for performance and security reasons.

For the wiki links, pre-process them before sending your text to the markdown parser.

Comment: I do not want to pre-process wiki links, because doing so e.g. with regexps would lead to all sorts of corner cases. This is the way git-wiki works currently.

Comment: I figured, but that doesn't mean it's your better option. Your better option is to actually deal with these corner cases and avoid the many regex-related security issues that are avoided in the c-library.